# C Multiple file program with linked list, removing node

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

This program should delete node from linked list( in my case from 10, 20, 30,..., 100 )which data is equal with the number you enter. It does not work properly. It should show full list but it stops after 10, gives to select number and breaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "LinkedList.c"

int main() {
    int x;
    int change=0;
    LINK head, curr, currB, tail;
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    currB = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    create_list(&head, &curr, &tail);
    print_list(head, curr);
    ask_for_value(&x);
    delete_node(head, curr, currB, tail, &change, x);
    if (0 == change)
        printf("\nValue %d is not on the list\n", x);
    print_list(head, curr);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "LinkedList.h"

void create_list(LINK *head, LINK *curr, LINK *tail) {
    int i;
    for(i=10; i<100; i+=10) {
        (*curr)=(LINK)malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
        (*curr)->data = i;
        if(i==10) {
            (*curr)->next = NULL;
            (*tail)=(*curr);
            (*head)=(*curr);
        }
        else {
            (*curr)->next = NULL;
            (*tail)->next = (*curr);
            (*tail)=(*curr);
        }
    }
}

void delete_node(LINK head, LINK curr, LINK currB, LINK tail, int *change, int x) {
    int i;
    if(head->data==x) {
        curr=head;
        head=curr->next;
        free(curr);
        (*change)=1;
        exit(0);
    }
    if(tail->data==x){
        curr=head;
        while(curr->next!=tail)
        curr=curr->next;
        free(tail);
        tail=curr;
        tail->next=NULL;
        (*change)=1;
        exit(0);
    }
    curr=currB=head;
    while(curr->data!=x || curr->next!=NULL){
        currB=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    if(curr->data!=x)
        exit(0);
    if(currB==curr){
        head=curr->next;
        free(curr);
        (*change)=1;
        exit(0);
    }
    currB->next=curr->next;
    free(curr);
    (*change)=1;
}

void print_list(LINK head, LINK curr)
{
    curr=head;
    if (curr!=NULL){
        printf("%d >> ",curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

void ask_for_value(int *x) {
    printf("Enter value which should be removed from the list\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
}
```

---

```
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H_
#define LINKED_LIST_H_

struct linkedList{
    int data;
    struct linkedList *next;
    };
typedef struct linkedList ELEMENT;
typedef struct linkedList *LINK;

void create_list(LINK *head, LINK *curr, LINK *tail);
void delete_node(LINK head, LINK curr, LINK currB, LINK tail, int *listChange, int x);
void print_list(LINK head, LINK curr);
void ask_for_value(int *x);
#endif
```

Second file is LinkedList.c and third one is LinkedList.h

---

EDIT: I've changed delete_node, works with any value except 10.

```
void delete_node(LINK head, LINK curr, LINK currB, LINK tail, int x) {
    curr=currB=head;
    while(curr->data!=x && curr->next!=NULL) {
        currB=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    if(head->data==x) {
        head=curr->next;
        free(currB);
    }
    else if(tail->data==x) {
        tail=currB;
        tail->next=NULL;
        free(curr);
    }
    else if(curr->data!=x) {
        printf("Element with given value could not be found!\n");
    }
    else{
        currB->next=curr->next;
        free(curr);
    }
}
```

Comment: your problem may be one of scope.  Look at the `extern` key word, Google usage examples, or search here.   `extern` allows you to define something in a header, and use it in multiple .c files (that include that header), while maintaining the same value in all of them at any point in time.  Similar in function to the effect of a  `static` used in a .c file, except with `extern`, visibility can be extended to an entire project.

Comment: The biggest problem with `delete_node` is that it uses `exit(0)` instead of a `return`. `exit(0)` terminates the program immediately, and that's not what you want. You just want to `return` from the subroutine. Also, you (almost) never want to `#include` a `.c` file in another `.c` file. So remove the `#include "LinkedList.c"` from `main.c` and compile with `gcc -Wall main.c LinkedList.c -o myProgram`

Comment: Linked-list with no aparrent debugging.  Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ask_for_value()` function,

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d", x);
```

Also, do not `#include` `.c` files. They are meant to be compiled.

Next, your `delete_node()` function is not proper. It will terminate the execution of your program by encountering `exit(0)` which is probably not what in wanted. You can use `return 0` instead.

Comment: I've fixed those mistakes you noted, also noticed that in print_list i changed from if to while to make a loop instead of single compare. But changing exit to return does not really makes a difference, non-stop outputs numbers, others drop not responding, only 100 gives right answer.

Comment: @DevGambit IMO, there are many issues in your code, specially in `delete_node()` function. Please read the comments in your original question. I see no reason to pass 6 arguments to `delete_node()`. Try to refine your logic a bit.

Comment: I've edited delete_node function, but deleting head value still does not work.